# Cant see the whole information in the run console Intellij

Tags: intellij-idea

im trying to do a `System.out.println` in intellij of a hash combination with the size of 3.I can't see the whole code when i run it, i only see part of the URL's that the hash has. Can someone help me? I know that putting images is bad here in stackoverflow but there's no other way of demonstrating this.
[image: Console Run]
As you can see here, the beggining doesn't show up and the scroll bar is at the top.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set bigger value for Console buffer (which is 1024 KB by default). Set it in Settings (Preferences on macOS) | Editor | General | Console | **Override console cycle buffer size (1024 KB)**:
[image]